# Can the MS Graph meeting link be opened directly in the browser?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have successfully created an onlineMeeting object by using MS Graph API

`POST /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings`

I can extract the joinWebUrl (or the joinUrl, both seem to be the same) and get it to open on a new tab, which gives a popup asking whether I should open the Teams App on my system to join the meeting. If I say yes, the Teams App opens up and I can join the meeting through it. If I say no, the Teams launcher page is opened, where I can

a. Download the app

b. Continue on the browser, or

c. Open Teams.

My question is, how can I get the meeting opened up directly on the browser, bypassing the popup and the launcher page? Everywhere I search, questions are on how to open the meeting directly in the app, but I need it the other way around, *in the browser*. Is this possible through code?

I'm including my graph API code below, even though it might not be relevant.

```
let data = {
        "startDateTime": "2022-08-16T13:20:34.2444915-07:00",
        "endDateTime": "2022-08-16T13:25:34.2444915-07:00",
        "subject": "Teams Meeting"
    }

    let payload = await fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    let json = await payload.json();

    window.open(json.joinWebUrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior is: it open the Teams launcher page:

[image: Teams launcher page is opened]

Here, you can click on checkbox to always open the links in associated app but we don't have any option to always open it in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! At least it confirms my search!